# Moshi Json - Decompiled code still shows annotated name

Tags: android, gson, proguard, decompiler, moshi

I am trying to enable code obfuscation in my android project. I am using `moshi` for json operations. I am having a problem with release apk file. When I use a decompiler the `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` annotated files are almost stays non-obfuscated in terms of reducing code readability. I can easily read the class name and also variable names. I attach original and obfuscated sample class code below. There is also an adapter class generated by `moshi` lib that also shows the readable class content. I used to be using `Gson` lib before and I was not having similar issues with it. I didn't add any `moshi` related lines to my `proguard-rules.pro` file. I am also sure that I didn't add any rules to `proguard-rules.pro` file related to keeping this annotated files. Am I missing a configuration update?

Gradle file

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Original class

```
import com.decompiletest.enum.EyeColor
import com.squareup.moshi.Json
import com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class MPerson(
    @Json(name = "name") val name: String,
    @Json(name = "lucy_number") val luckyNumber: Int,
    @Json(name = "eye_color") val eyeColor: EyeColor,
)
```

Obfuscated version

```
import p002a1.C1300j;
import p002a1.C1303m;
import p026f1.C0403d;
import p099y0.C1202a;

@C1303m(generateAdapter = true)
/* renamed from: com.decompiletest.moshis.MPerson */
public final class MPerson {

    /* renamed from: a */
    public final String f759a;

    /* renamed from: b */
    public final int f760b;

    /* renamed from: c */
    public final C1202a f3861c;

    public MPerson(@C1300j(name = "name") String str, @C1300j(name = "lucy_number") int i, @C1300j(name = "eye_color") C1202a aVar) {
        C0403d.m3330r(str, "name");
        C0403d.m3330r(aVar, "eyeColor");
        this.f759a = str;
        this.f760b = i;
        this.f3861c = aVar;
    }

    public final MPerson copy(@C1300j(name = "name") String str, @C1300j(name = "lucy_number") int i, @C1300j(name = "eye_color") C1202a aVar) {
        C0403d.m3330r(str, "name");
        C0403d.m3330r(aVar, "eyeColor");
        return new MPerson(str, i, aVar);
    }

    public final boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof MPerson)) {
            return false;
        }
        MPerson mPerson = (MPerson) obj;
        return C0403d.m3322d(this.f759a, mPerson.f759a) && this.f760b == mPerson.f760b && this.f3861c == mPerson.f3861c;
    }

    public final int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = Integer.hashCode(this.f760b);
        return this.f3861c.hashCode() + ((hashCode + (this.f759a.hashCode() * 31)) * 31);
    }

    public final String toString() {
        return "MPerson(name=" + this.f759a + ", luckyNumber=" + this.f760b + ", eyeColor=" + this.f3861c + ")";
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Zac Sweers from Moshi library contributers mentioned the following;

> This is working as intended. Code gen generates proguard rules on the
> fly to conditionally keep class names and primary constructors in
> order to reflectively instantiate them at runtime.
> https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1757

Comment: Moshi has [its own ProGuard / R8 configuration](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/moshi.pro) which is applied when you use it as dependency. Maybe that configuration keeps too much by accident / disables obfuscation where it could remain enabled.

Comment: @Marcono1234 yes that should be the reason.

Comment: For future reference, it looks like you also created an issue on the Moshi repository: https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/1757 (in the future please link such posts so that other users can easily find this information)

Comment: yes I forgot to mention it. thank you for reminding me.